# Change object type in to datetime64[ns]-pandas

Tags: python, time, pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing web server log files and having date time in following format.

```
02/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530
```

I'm converting this into pandas date-time format.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

But still it is in the object format.

```
print df.dtypes
```

Time        object

why it is not changing to `datetime64[ns]`?

Numpy version

```
In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Following answer depends on your python version.*

Pandas' `to_datetime` can't recognize your custom datetime format, you should provide it explicetly:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['02/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530']},index=['tst'])
>>> from functools import partial
>>> to_datetime_fmt = partial(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
```

and apply this custom converter

```
>>> df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(to_datetime_fmt)
>>> df.dtypes
Time    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Note, however that it works from python version **3.2**, in earlier versions `%z` is unsupported. You have to add timedelta manually.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['02/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530']},index=['tst'])
```

Split time into datetime and offset

```
>>> def strptime_with_offset(string, format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'):
...    base_dt = datetime.strptime(string[:-6], format)
...    offset = int(string[-6:])
...    delta = timedelta(hours=offset/100, minutes=offset%100)
...    return base_dt + delta
...
```

and apply this conversion function:

```
>>> df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(strptime_with_offset)
>>> df['Time']
tst   2013-04-03 05:25:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df.dtypes
Time    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks verymuch for your answer. It gives following error. Why it adds a space? ValueError: time data '02/Apr/2013 23:55:00' does not match format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'

Comment: first, may be your real data is `02/Apr/2013 23:55:00`. you may use appropriate format, such as `'%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S'`. second, my answer is not quite correct, gonna update it soon

Comment: No my real data is in the format you have posted. Eg. [02/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530],[02/Apr/2013:23:55:09 +0530],[02/Apr/2013:23:55:18 +0530] etc.

Comment: May be some conversion happens when you load data, try check what dt['Time'] output is. I updated my answer with correct conversion function, don't have enough time to dig in previous code to find out where error is (probably some issue with how pandas stores timedelta).

Answer (score 8):

Sorry if I missed something...

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64')
```

Comment: I get two errors:
1. ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
2. ValueError: Array must be all same time zone

Answer (score 0):

Apart from alko's approach this code also worked fine.

```
from dateutil import parser

def parse(x):
    date, hh, mm, ss = x.split(':')
    dd, mo, yyyy = date.split('/')
    return parser.parse("%s %s %s %s:%s:%s" % (yyyy,mo,dd,hh,mm,ss))

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x:x[1:-7])
```

Comment: Be aware that here you intentinally omit offset `+0530` and get different result, `2013-04-02 23:55:00` instead of `2013-04-03 05:25:00`. I don't know what result is _desired_ but latter seems to be better suited, as your datas can possibly have different offsets.

Comment: And it has to be `-6`, not `-7`, either you should get `ValueError()`