# Convert dd-mmm-yyyy (object) to dd-mm-yyyy (datetime64)

Tags: pandas

How to convert a pandas dataframe dd-mmm-yyyy (object) to dd-mm-yyyy (datetime64)?

Example: 25-Oct-2021 (dtype object) to 25-10-2021 (dtype datetime64)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change object type in to datetime64\[ns\]-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764230/change-object-type-in-to-datetime64ns-pandas)

Comment: No. I want dd-mm-yyyy (dtype datetime64), where as the suggested link converts to yyyy-mm-dd (dtype datetime64).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
```

Comment: Tried:     'df1['ed'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ed'], format='%d-%b-%Y')' # Converts to datetime64 but format is yyyy-mm-dd. I want dd-mm-yyyy.

Tried:         'df1['ed'] = df1['ed'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')' # Converts to dd-mm-yyyy but makes it object. I want datetime64.