# Pandas pd.to_datetime() assigns object dtype instead of datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have encountered an issue while using the pd.to_datetime() function in pandas. When I try to convert the "datetime" column in my DataFrame to a datetime64[ns] dtype using the .loc method, the dtype remains as an object. However, using the direct assignment with square brackets, the conversion works correctly, resulting in the datetime64[ns] dtype as expected.

Version, that does not work:

```py
df.loc[:, "datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print(df.dtypes)

####### Results #######
id            int64
testcolumn    object
datetime      object
value         object
```

Version, that does work (but only with generating a new column):

```py
df.loc[:, "foo"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print(df.dtypes)

####### Results #######
id            int64
testcolumn    object
datetime      object
value         object
foo           datetime64[ns]
```

Version, that also works:

```py
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print(df.dtypes)

####### Results #######
id            int64
testcolumn    object
datetime      datetime64[ns]
value         object
```

I'm confused as to why the first code snippet fails to convert the "datetime" column to datetime64[ns] properly, while the second code snippet successfully accomplishes the conversion. The only difference between the two code snippets is the method of assigning the converted values back to the DataFrame.

Can someone explain why the first code snippet using .loc does not work as expected for converting the dtype to datetime64[ns]? Additionally, I would appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to perform the conversion using .loc or reasons why it behaves differently compared to direct assignment with square brackets.

Here is a MVCE:

```py
import pandas as pd # version: '2.0.1'

# Sample data for the DataFrame
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'testcolumn': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'datetime': ['2023-07-25 10:30:00', '2023-07-26 12:45:00', '2023-07-27 15:15:00'],
    'value': ['100', '200', '300']
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[:, "datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print(df.dtypes)

df.loc[:, "foo"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print(df.dtypes)

df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: I am having troubles duplicating this error, can you write a MVCE?

Comment: @ScottBoston I have added a MVCE

Comment: Yep.  Looks buggy.  Works fine in 1.5.3 pandas.

Comment: I cannot recreate your MVCE. I am getting `datetime` and `foo` as `datetime64[ns]`. I'm on pandas 1.4.3.

Comment: But could duplicate in 2.0.3.  Probably should look at doing bug report.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change object type in to datetime64\[ns\]-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764230/change-object-type-in-to-datetime64ns-pandas)

Comment: @Mark No it does not.

Comment: Same here. If I try to operate on these apparently mixed-typed columns I get `PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized`

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR

This is expected behaviour in `pd` version `2.0.x`. It is best to avoid using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if you want to assign a new array to a column in a `df`, both in `2.0.x` and earlier. Use [`DataFrame.__setitem__()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isetitem.html) directly, amounting to:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# datetime64[ns]
```

- In version `2.0.x`, `df.loc[:, foo] = bar` will only change the dtype, *when necessary*.
- In earlier versions, `df.loc[:, foo] = bar` will change the dtype, when you "[set] an entire column from an array with different dtype".

---

##### Behaviour `df.loc[:, foo] = bar` and `df.iloc[:, foo] = bar` in `pd` version `2.0.x`

From [What's new in 2.0.0 (April 3, 2023)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes):

> Changed behavior in setting values with `df.loc[:, foo] = bar` or `df.iloc[:, foo] = bar`, these now always attempt to set values inplace before falling back to casting ([GH 45333](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45333))

Since your original column has dtype `object`, it is possible to set the values inplace, so that indeed is what happens. Notice that the values *do* change into `Timestamp` values, it is just that the operation does not change the dtype, because it does not need to do that: dtype `object` can contain `Timestamp` values:

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)
# '2.0.3'

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'testcolumn': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'datetime': ['2023-07-25 10:30:00', '2023-07-26 12:45:00', 
                 '2023-07-27 15:15:00'],
    'value': ['100', '200', '300']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# object

print(type(df.loc[0, 'datetime']))
# <class 'str'>

df.loc[:, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# object

print(type(df.loc[0, 'datetime']))
# <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

So, it is also not surprising that `df.loc[:, 'foo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])` does lead to dtype `datetime64[ns]`. In this case, there is no previously associated dtype, as the column did not yet exist.

Suppose we would first change the dtype of column `"datetime"` to `string`, then the operation would get you the desired result. This is because a column of dtype `string` can only contain strings. So, in this case the operation indeed "fall[s] back to casting", necessarily altering the dtype:

```
print(pd.__version__)
# '2.0.3'

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype('string')

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# string

df.loc[:, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# datetime64[ns]
```

---

##### Behaviour `df.loc[:, foo] = bar` and `df.iloc[:, foo] = bar` in earlier `pd` versions

The confusion arises from the fact that the behaviour used to be different. The previous behaviour is described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#inplace-operation-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc):

> Most of the time setting values with `DataFrame.iloc()` attempts to set values inplace, only falling back to inserting a new array if necessary. *There are some cases where this rule is not followed, for example when setting an entire column from an array with different dtype*[.] (my italics)

Since we are indeed "setting an entire column from an array with different dtype", in these earlier versions the dtype *is* changed. For example:

```
print(pd.__version__)
# '1.4.1'

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[:, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# datetime64[ns]
```

Note that in version `1.5.3` you receive a `DeprecationWarning` when you perform this operation, raising awareness of the future change, now implemented in `2.0.x`:

```
print(pd.__version__)
# '1.5.3'

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')

try:
    df.loc[:, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
except DeprecationWarning as warning:
    print(warning)
    
# In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values 
# inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use 
# either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, 
# `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`

print(df['datetime'].dtypes)
# datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This confused me big time, thanks for the clarification. I am used to `.loc` to set new values and avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`. However, I am getting `PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized` when operating on these apparently mixed-type datetime cols: existing columns are `Object`, new ones are `datetime64`...